# Feature Extraction and Vector Space Model

Tags: feature-extraction, word2vec

I have a dataset of reviews and I want to extract the features along with their opinion words in the reviews.

Is it possible to extract features from my data using any Vector Space Model?(TF-IDF, Word2Vec, etc.)

Edit for sample data:

```
"Teacher", "Subject", "Feedback"
"Dr. Tayal","Discrete Mathematics","He has very good subject knowledge. He didn't take all the lectures. He teaches and explains concepts very well."
"Ms Vibha","OOPS","Subject knowledge is poor, but she is regular with classes. She is unnecassrily strict and does not teach the subject nicely."
```

Comment: Add a small chunk of your dataset in the question, which can help the  answerer have an idea about your dataset.

Comment: @Dawny33 hopefully the edited question enlightens you now.